# ¿Es posible almacenar la data de un Email en un spreadsheet?

Tags: javascript, email, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

muy buenas
estuve investigando en internet la manera de hacer que el texto de un correo electronico se almacene en una spreadsheet de google, pero no entiendo como hacerlo.
para ser más amplio con la explicación, si yo recibo un correo electronico como podría obtener el asunto del correo popularlo en una spreadsheet?,
hay alguna manera de hacerlo con google Script?

muchas gracias por sus comentarios.

Comment: Existe la api de Gmail que puedes usar dentro de un google Script. Puedes ver mas en este enlace https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/apps-script. Puedes usar la api user.messages https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages para obtener los mensajes recibidos y alimentar la hoja

Comment: ¿El mail es de gmail, de algún otro masivo en la nube o de un tercero?

Comment: Muchas gracias, el mail es de Gmail

Answer (score 0):

Si es posible.

Para leer los datos del mensaje puedes usar el servicio `GmailApp` y para escrirlos en la hoja de cálculo puedes usar el servicio `SpreadsheetApp`

Además de los servicios anteriores podrías usar los servicios avanzados de Gmail y de Google Sheets.

Recursos

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script